# Defining multiple-type container classes in haskell, trouble binding variables

Tags: class, haskell, functional-programming

I'm having trouble with classes in haskell.

Basically, I have an algorithm (a weird sort of graph-traversal algorithm) that takes as input, among other things, a container to store the already-seen nodes (I'm keen on avoiding monads, so let's move on. :)). The thing is, the function takes the container as a parameter, and calls just one function: "set_contains", which asks if the container... contains node v. (If you're curious, another function passed in as a parameter does the actual node-adding).

Basically, I want to try a variety of data structures as parameters. Yet, as there is no overloading, I cannot have more than one data structure work with the all-important contains function!

So, I wanted to make a "Set" class (I shouldn't roll my own, I know). I already have a pretty nifty Red-Black tree set up, thanks to Chris Okasaki's book, and now all that's left is simply *making the Set class and declaring RBT, among others, as instances of it*.

Here is the following code:

(Note: code heavily updated -- e.g., contains now does not call a helper function, but is the class function itself!)

```
data Color = Red | Black
data (Ord a) => RBT a = Leaf | Tree Color (RBT a) a (RBT a)

instance Show Color where
    show Red = "r"
    show Black = "b"

class Set t where
    contains :: (Ord a) => t-> a-> Bool

-- I know this is nonesense, just showing it can compile.
instance (Ord a) => Eq (RBT a) where
    Leaf == Leaf = True
    (Tree _ _ x _) == (Tree _ _ y _) = x == y

instance (Ord a) => Set (RBT a) where
    contains Leaf b = False
    contains t@(Tree c l x r) b
        | b == x    = True
        | b < x     = contains l b
        | otherwise = contains r b
```

Note how I have a pretty stupidly-defined Eq instance of RBT. That is intentional --- I copied it (but cut corners) from [the gentle tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Basically, my question boils down to this: If I comment out the instantiation statement for Set (RBT a), everything compiles. If I add it back in, I get the following error:

```
RBTree.hs:21:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `a1'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `contains' at RBTree.hs:11:21
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the instance declaration at RBTree.hs:18:14
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `x'
    In a pattern guard for
       the definition of `contains':
          b == x
    In the definition of `contains':
        contains (t@(Tree c l x r)) b
                   | b == x = True
                   | b < x = contains l b
                   | otherwise = contains r b
```

And I simply cannot, for the life of me, figure out why that isn't working. (As a side note, the "contains" function is defined elsewhere, and basically has the actual set_contains logic for the RBT data type.)

Thanks! - Agor

Third edit: removed the previous edits, consolidated above.

Comment: @Agor: in what sense are the containers "multiple-type containers"?

Comment: @yairchu: I suppose that's not the right label, but I can't think of a better one. I'm trying to express the fact that, while I'm trying to make a Set of type t, it contains a different type a, and that's causing issues. Or at least, that *was*, but the answers here have been quite helpful. :) Regardless, I agree that my title is a little clunky, and if there is a better way of writing it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use [higher-kinded polyphormism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). The way your class is defined it sort of expects a type t which has [kind](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo) *. What you probably want is that your Set class takes a container type, like your RBT which has kind * -> *.

You can easily modify your class to give your type t a kind * -> * by applying `t` to a type variable, like this:

```
class Set t where
    contains :: (Ord a) => t a -> a -> Bool
```

and then modify your instance declaration to remove the type variable `a`:

```
instance Set RBT where
    contains Leaf b = False
    contains t@(Tree c l x r) b
        | b == x    = True
        | b < x     = contains l b
        | otherwise = contains r b
```

So, here is the full modified code with a small example at the end:

```
data Color = Red | Black
data (Ord a) => RBT a = Leaf | Tree Color (RBT a) a (RBT a)

instance Show Color where
    show Red = "r"
    show Black = "b"

class Set t where
    contains :: (Ord a) => t a -> a -> Bool

-- I know this is nonesense, just showing it can compile.
instance (Ord a) => Eq (RBT a) where
    Leaf == Leaf = True
    (Tree _ _ x _) == (Tree _ _ y _) = x == y

instance Set RBT where
    contains Leaf b = False
    contains t@(Tree c l x r) b
        | b == x    = True
        | b < x     = contains l b
        | otherwise = contains r b

tree = Tree Black (Tree Red Leaf 3 Leaf) 5 (Tree Red Leaf 8 (Tree Black Leaf 12 Leaf))

main =
    putStrLn ("tree contains 3: " ++ test1) >>
    putStrLn ("tree contains 12: " ++ test2) >>
    putStrLn ("tree contains 7: " ++ test3)
    where test1 = f 3
          test2 = f 12
          test3 = f 7
          f = show . contains tree
```

If you compile this, the output is

```
tree contains 3: True
tree contains 12: True
tree contains 7: False
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this one the answer because it doesn't require any language extensions. I have nothing against language extensions, but as this answer demonstrates, I don't yet know the core language (very well) yet either! First things first, I suppose.

(Also, I would I could +1 again for the working code example, thank!)

Answer (score 4):

You need a *multi-parameter type class*. Your current definition of `Set t` doesn't mention the contained type in the class definition, so the member `contains` has to work for any `a`. Try this:

```
class Set t a | t -> a where
    contains :: (Ord a) => t-> a-> Bool


instance (Ord a) => Set (RBT a) a where
    contains Leaf b = False
    contains t@(Tree c l x r) b
        | b == x    = True
        | b < x     = contains l b
        | otherwise = contains r b
```

The `| t -> a` bit of the definition is a *functional dependency*, saying that for any given `t` there is only one possible `a`. It's useful to have (when it makes sense) since it helps the compiler figure out types and reduces the number of ambiguous type problems you often otherwise get with multi-parameter type classes.

You'll also need to enable the language extensions `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies` at the top of your source file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
```

Comment: imho TypeFamilies are nicer than FunctionalDependencies.. see the code with families below

Comment: Personally I don't think they're yet mature enough to recommend to newbies - I use them extensively myself, and there are lots of gotchas and a few unimplemented pieces. Once they're done I agree they'll be much nicer.

Comment: While I didn't mark this one the answer, I appreciate being introduced to some nifty new language extensions (I really don't know much about them yet), and I *think* I understand what it is you're saying. +1, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the types don't match. What is the type of `contains`? (If its type is not something like `t -> a -> Bool` as `set_contains` is, something is wrong.)

Comment: +1 because I think its helping, but I still have the same sort of type error. I'm going to update the code changes I've made shortly, but thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you shouldn't roll your own classes?

When you write the instance for `Set (RBT a)`, you define contains for the specific type `a` only. I.e. `RBT Int` is a set of `Int`s, `RBT Bool` is a set of `Bools`, etc.

But your definition of `Set t` requires that `t` be a set of *all* ordered `a`'s at the same time!

That is, this should typecheck, given the type of `contains`:

```
tree :: RBT Bool
tree = ...

foo = contains tree 1
```

and it obviously won't.

There are three solutions:

1. Make `t` a type constructor variable:

   class Set t where 
     contains :: (Ord a) => t a -> a-> Bool

   instance Set RBT where
     ...

This will work for `RBT`, but not for many other cases (for example, you may want to use a bitset as a set of `Int`s.

2. Functional dependency:

   class (Ord a) => Set t a | t -> a where
     contains :: t -> a -> Bool

   instance (Ord a) => Set (RBT a) a where
     ...

See [GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) for details.

3. Associated types:

   class Set t where
     type Element t :: *
     contains :: t -> Element t -> Bool

   instance (Ord a) => Set (RBT a) where
     type Element (RBT a) = a
     ...

See [GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ganesh's answer, you can use Type Families instead of Functional Dependencies. Imho they are nicer. And they also change your code less.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

class Set t where
  type Elem t
  contains :: (Ord (Elem t)) => t -> Elem t -> Bool

instance (Ord a) => Set (RBT a) where
  type Elem (RBT a) = a
  contains Leaf b = False
  contains (Tree c l x r) b
    | b == x    = True
    | b < x     = contains l b
    | otherwise = contains r b
```

Comment: Ooooh, those are nifty too. Thanks! But as I said in reply the_edge, I think I'll hold off on using complex language extensions until I have a better grounding.